# How to play an encrypted audio file in ios?

Tags: ios

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://********/uploads/downloads/194837412f5b3d310109b7a777d0f589.mp3"];       
NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData  error:NULL];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer play];
```

I am getting without encrypted audio file by this way and its working nice...but when i am trying to get encrypted audio file it is not working   I need your help to play an encrypted audio file . Please give answer with example...Thank you...I am new in ios Development

Comment: We store some music in our server with encrypted format.But i don't know how I can play it in iOS AVAudioPlayer?Is it possible using AVAudioPlayer?if not how i can play it.

Comment: I have encryption key..but i don't know the process . how to call the audio file with key.

Comment: Add the information from the comments to the question.

Comment: I edited your question to fix your grammar, and to include the information that you provided in the comments. Please accept my edit, it makes your question much more readable.

Comment: You need to decrypt the audio data, but to decrypt it you need to know how it was encrypted.  Do you know how it was encrypted?

Comment: Following link i got one way  to decrepit the file but it is not clear to me...Can any one help ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042583/playing-an-encrypted-mp3-in-ios